# Error while reading user from Firebase Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I get an error while trying to read and store user email.

addroom.page.ts:
constructor:

```
constructor(private crudService: CrudService, private fbauth: AngularFireAuth) { }
```

Method:

```
async createRecord() {
    const user = await this.fbauth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
    const record = {};
    record['Name'] = this.roomName;
    record['Number'] = this.roomNumber;
    record['Description'] = this.roomDescription;
    record['User'] = user;
    this.crudService.create_NewRoom(record).then(resp => {
      this.roomName = "";
      this.roomNumber = undefined;
      this.roomDescription = "";
      this.roomUser = user.email;
      console.log(resp);
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

service.ts(CrudService):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CrudService {

  constructor(
    private firestore: AngularFirestore
  ) { }

  create_NewRoom(record) {
    return this.firestore.collection('Rooms').add(record);
  }

  read_Rooms() {
    return this.firestore.collection('Rooms').snapshotChanges();
  }

  update_Room(recordID,record){
    this.firestore.doc('Rooms/' + recordID).update(record);
  }

  delete_Room(recordID) {
    this.firestore.doc('Rooms/' + recordID).delete();
  }
}
```

Imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudService } from '../service/service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";
```

And I get an error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Q object (found in field User)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Like the error suggest, you cannot store a custom object, in this case a `Firebase.User`.

Comment: @AJT82 Can you offer me a solution then? I'm pretty new to Angular.

Comment: Please try this code to set  the record :     
  record['User'].doc().set(Object.assign({}, user))

Comment: @junlan now I get: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'doc' of undefined

Comment: @AJT82 I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error suggest, you cannot store custom objects, in this case a `Firebase.User`. You need to extract the properties you want, for example:

```
record['User'] = { email: user.email, displayName: user.displayName };
```

I though like to work with a table, where I store all data related to a user, for easier access and no need to extract specific data. So in this case I would just store uid of the user when creating "new room" and have the user data in a separate table. That is just my suggestion :)

Comment: But now when I try to read it the same way I read other strings, I get: [object Object]. Any suggestions how I could convert it to String so it would display an email address?

Comment: I'm trying to access it with: <ion-card-subtitle>Added by: {{room.User}}</ion-card-subtitle> but I only get [object Object], while console.log shows the actualy email as User: {email: "email@gmail.com"}. But I want that reading: record['User'] = { email: user.email } would be shown as a String.

Comment: yeah,  `User` is an object, remember? :) So needs to be `{{room?.User?.email}}` I just added the safe navigation operator, don't know if you need it.